# Json Ajax and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, dynamic

I just want to know how I can make periodically check for any update and reflect the change in relevant cell if it gets updated and should flash it along with changing the color to red/green based on negative or positive change if it is a numeric value.

Using Jquery, Ajax and json...

Regards
Nidhi...

Comment: You have three separate problems there. Deal with each one in turn. I suggest starting with the jQuery documentation.

Comment: You can't just tell us how you'd like your web product to be, and ask us for the source code for such a product. You would have to describe a specific problem that you're facing, and ask for assistance on how to solve that problem.

Comment: I Have Some json data, Using ajax I am displaying in Table format but I want to add some additional feature I want to add some periodically check that if data is changed , I am not sure how to check that data changed , There is one property in $.ajax isModified but that will fetch only changed data.. I am not sure how to start with if some one can guide me , Not looking for excat code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
.good{
   border:solid thin #green;
}
.bad{
   border:solid thin #red;
}
</style>
/// your ajax call can be simple like this
<script>
var url = 'your file where your php code while procces.php';
$.post(url,{'varname':'varvalue'},function(data){
   if(data == '.. your control value 1'){
      $('your div you want to cahnge').addclass('.good');
   }else{
      $('your div you want to cahnge').addclass('.bad');
   }
})
</script>
```

Comment: I have table multiple table cell how I can test that data has been changed

Comment: Please do so... I am not able to understand how do I compare old data which is now stored in table and new data which is in json format...